# JSON structuring a groupchat

Tags: json, firebase

I'm going to implement a groupchat into my app by using Firebase. I were thinking of 2 different structures of saving data in JSON.

First structure:
[image: Picture of my idea of a structure]
Second structure:
[image: Picture of my second structure]

I would like to achieve a fast query and i would like it to parse a small amount of data each time. What structure should i go for and are there maybe a better alternative then these 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first solution is clearly not viable, as you would have a hard time finding all messages belonging to a given group.

The second solution is ok if *every time* you will query a given group's node, you are going to need also *all* of its messages, which is probably not what you want.

It is hard, of course, to advise on data structure without more info on your use-case, the queries you are going to make, etc., but a rather standard approach would be:

```
{
    "users": {
        "$userId"": {
            // user data
        }
    },
    "groups": {
        "$groupId": {
            // group data
        }
    },
    "group_users": {
        "$groupId": {
            "$userId": true
            // separation of list of users from the group is useful
            // if you are going to query the group node not needing its full list of users
        }
    },
    "group_messages": {
        "$groupId": {
            "$messageId": {
                // message data
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer VonD. I've gotten a better understanding on how to structure the data in JSON. I'll definitely try this structure since my chat is really simple.